# How to call a sql query and pass a parameter from another table?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a complex sql query, named qryARAT2B_EXT.

```
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         * 
      FROM
         (
            SELECT
               *,
               firstStudy,
               ABS(DATEDIFF('d', firstStudy, Check_Date)) as diff 
            FROM
               (
                  SELECT
                     *,
                     (
                        SELECT
                           TOP 1 Check_Date 
                        FROM
                           qryARAT2B 
                        WHERE
                           PATNR = [PАРАМ] 
                        ORDER BY
                           Check_Date 
                     )
                     AS firstStudy 
                  FROM
                     (
                        SELECT
                           * 
                        FROM
                           qryARAT2B 
                        WHERE
                           PATNR = [PАРАМ]
                     )
                     AS myPatientsWithStudy 
               )
               AS myPatientsFirstStudy 
         )
      WHERE
         diff = 0
   )
   AS T1 
   LEFT JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            * 
         FROM
            (
               SELECT
                  *,
                  firstStudy,
                  ABS(DATEDIFF('d', firstStudy, Check_Date)) as diff 
               FROM
                  (
                     SELECT
                        *,
                        (
                           SELECT
                              TOP 1 Check_Date 
                           FROM
                              qryARAT2B 
                           WHERE
                              PATNR = [PАРАМ] 
                           ORDER BY
                              Check_Date 
                        )
                        AS firstStudy 
                     FROM
                        (
                           SELECT
                              * 
                           FROM
                              qryARAT2B 
                           WHERE
                              PATNR = [PАРАМ] 
                        )
                        AS myPatientsWithStudy 
                  )
                  AS myPatientsFirstStudy 
            )
         WHERE
            diff = 4
      )
      As T2 
      ON T1.PATNR = T2.PATNR
```

When I open it in ms-access, it asks for the value of the [PARAM] and produces the result.

I have a table of patients.
    tblPatient with the columns:
    PATNR, and s.o.

That contains the PATNR's of patients:

```
000001
000002
...
XXXXXX
```

I need to write sql to calculate data for all PATNR's at once.
something like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT * FROM qryARAT2B_EXT WHERE [PARAM] = PATNR) from tblPatient
```

But it is not accepted from ms-access. I'm not able to pass parameter to qryARAT2B_EXT from the SQL. Is there any specific syntax for it in ms-access?

Comment: `SELECT (SELECT * FROM qryARAT2B_EXT WHERE [PARAM] = PATNR) from tblPatient` - you have to select at least one field (or *) in the outer query. That applies to any DB engine, not just Access.

Comment: Something like this:
<code>
    (select PATNR from tblPatient As K
        LEFT JOIN
             (SELECT * FROM qryARAT2B_EXT WHERE [PARAM] = K.PATNR) As K1
    ON K1.PATNR = K.PATNR
    )
</code>

Comment: But how can I pass parameter K.PATNR to sub sql?

Comment: surely it would just be `WHERE [PARAM] = qryARAT2B_EXT.PATNR` in the subquery? The Join will take care of restricting what's returned from `K`

Comment: Thanks, but I need to pass PATNR from tblPatient, not from qryARAT2B_EXT. Is there any possibility to pass parameter from main select to sub select?